# Disable Darken Colors for UIToolBarButtons

Tags: ios, user-interface, accessibility

iOS 7 introduced the "Darken Colors" Accessibility Setting to introduce contrast. The theme of one of my clients' products uses white in the toolbar for tint with the bar being tinted a teal color. When this setting is turned on, the buttons go gray and actually reduce contrast and are hard to use!

Is there a way to turn this off? I know there is an Apple API that lets you know the user has dark mode enabled, but it appears to always darken my UIToolBarButton's tint by 20%. I don't want this!

Any insight or workarounds most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yo can read `navigationBar.tintColor`. This returns your colour. After that, you can set `navigationBar.titleTextAttributes` with that colour. That is a workaround. And use `imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` for images for all your elements that can be tinted. I hope this helps you.